# Warning on confirmation screen for event registration

Tags: civievent

When the user clicks the "review your registration button" the confirmation screen gives a warning.

> Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a
> string or an integer in
> /home/customer/www/crm.coma.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Array.php
> on line 39

Everything works if they click "continue" but we think this message may be putting off people from registering.

I don't really know when this started, but the only thing I have changed recently is to install Cividiscount. I'm running CiviCRM 5.35.1 on WordPress. The version of Cividiscount that installed was 3.8.2 which should be OK. Disabling Cividiscount doesn't help.

Comment: if this was a drupal site, then 'showing warnings' is a setting that can be turned off. not saying it would be a good solution (nor that this would be a warning that would disappear if warnings were turned off) but since no one else has yet answered i thought i would mention it as perhaps wp has a similar setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit more testing and found that the online booking for the event behaved normally if I changed the profile to the standard event one so suspected the new custom fields that I had created for participants. I found that a field with a numeric type and dropdown selection for entry was the cause of the problem. Creating a new custom field with alphanumeric type solved the problem. My dropdown options weren't numeric so maybe that was the problem.